# Jmeter startup consuming 14g memory in non gui mode without usage of any listener

Tags: java, jmeter, heap-memory

I am using Jmeter in non GUI and not using any listener as of now. Jmeter is taking 14 g of memory at the time of start up in 4.0 version and 9g of memory in 5.0 version with out passing any configuration file and as the load is increasing (in 1 sec 250 request with loop count of 100) memory utilization is 32g. I do not want to increase heap size, can you tell me the solution how i can reduce the memory consumption?

[Virtual memory usgae through top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CKHR.png)

[Simple jmx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB26d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you cannot as heap utilization depends on the nature of your test, request and response sizes, number of [Pre](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[Post](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) Processors/[Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.

1. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Consider using a profiler tool i.e. [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [Heap Dump](https://dzone.com/articles/memory-analysis-how-to-obtain-java-heat-dump) /  [Heap Analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091) to figure out which component(s) is consuming the heap
3. If you don't have enough RAM and suffer from intensive [GC](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) activities the only way of speeding your test up is going for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) - this way you will be able to decrease the number of threads for each JMeter engine.

Comment: It is taking too much swap memory if we run command sh jmeter -n -e or sh jmeter -n -t test.jmx(in jmx file we are using only user thread group with 1 thread in 1 sec with loop count 1 only) and at the same time if we use top command it will show the virtual memory utilization that is 14g that is too much for 1 request.

Comment: It might be the case that either somewhere in `jmeter` startup script you have `-Xms` argument or there is `JVM_ARGS` environment variable which is being consumed by the script. You can try out launching JMeter as `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t test.jmx` and the heap usage should go down.

Comment: I added sample images for simple jmx file and top command results.

Comment: I run this java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t test.jmx and checked through top command , virtual memory usage increased to 36g for version 4.0